# Grails 2.5.5 in Eclipse with Groovy Compiler 2.4.12 throws Refresh Dependencies error

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I have installed Grails 2.5.5 in Eclipse GGTS (3.6.4.RELEASE) and have added  Groovy Compiler feature 2.4.12.  I am importing existing projects into the workspace.

Before updating the compiler, refresh dependencies (on a new project) worked without problems.  Now, when I run Refresh Dependencies (alt+g,r), it throws an error.  I am looking for guidance to help resolve the issue.  The log shows the following

```
!ENTRY org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2017-07-25 18:43:19.426
!MESSAGE Refresh dependecies failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/frameworkadapter/util/SpecifiedVersion
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.getRequiredGroovyVersion(GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.java:63)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.getRequiredGroovyVersion(GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.java:57)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.check(GroovyCompilerVersionCheck.java:50)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommandUtils.refreshDependencies(GrailsCommandUtils.java:327)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.internal.classpath.GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.runInWorkspace(GrailsClasspathContainerUpdateJob.java:89)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

This is an issue present in a specific version of the `groovy-eclipse` plugin. As far as I know the issue is present in `groovy-eclipse` v2.9.2.xx-201707260047-e44 (groovy compiler v2.4.12).

Since then [the issue has ben reported and fixed](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/322).

### Solution

To solve the problem simply update the `groovy-eclipse` plugin to v2.9.2.xx-201707311844-e44 or newer:

- In the *Help* menu select *Install New Software*
- Select or add the source `http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.4/` in the *Work with* field
- In the *Groovy Compilers* category select the *Groovy Compiler 2.4* item
- Clic *Next* and proceed with the update
- Restart GGTS to apply the changes